# Subdomain with Query String HTaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I have the following htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index-merchant.php?id=%1 [NC,QSA]
```

It can capture $_GET['id'] value, but now I wanna add something in

I want to capture

```
sub.domain.com/anything1/anylength
sub.domain.com/anything1/anything2/anything3
```

I want to capture anything1/anything2/anything3 as $_GET['query_string'];
The query string can be of any form of length, in summary if possible I would like capture it as wildcard (.*)

How do I make my .htaccess able to capture $_GET['query_string'] and $_GET['id'] which is my subdomain

Thanks!

Comment: This is extremely simple to achieve. Have you not tried anything as yet?

Comment: I did tried RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index-merchant.php?id=%1&q=%2 [NC,QSA] but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use `%` matches, as these are reserved for groups captured in `RewriteCond` only. You need to use the dollar sign `$` instead, and remember to start from 1 again:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index-merchant.php?id=%1&q=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Now, a request to `sub.domain.com/anything1/anylength` will rewrite to `/index-merchant.php?id=sub&q=anything1/anylength`.

Also, add the `L` flag (as shown) in case you decide to add any other rules below this one.